# MongoDB C++ Driver Assertion Failure

Tags: c++, mongodb, exception, insert, assertion

#### The Problem

When I try to insert a document into MongoDB with the C++ driver, I get the following exception message:

```
Wed Feb 27 15:21:38   Assertion failure p src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h 1096
0 assertion src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h:1096
```

From what I can tell, it seems to have something to do with the port number? dbclientinterface.h:1096 contains the following line:

```
MessagingPort& port() { verify(p); return *p; }
```

#### Setting up the connection (main.cpp)

```
mongo::DBClientConnection DBConn( "localhost" );
mongo::DBClientConnection DBConn( "localhost:27017" ); // I've also tried this...
```

#### Inserting a document (different_file.h)

```
while( m_Entries.size() ){
    JsonBox::Value Data( m_Entries.front() );

    try {
        std::stringstream   JSONDoc;
        mongo::BSONObj      BSONDoc;

        Data["doc"].writeToStream( JSONDoc, false );
        BSONDoc = mongo::fromjson( JSONDoc.str() );

        // std::cout << Data["ns"].getString() << std::endl;
        // std::cout << BSONDoc.toString() << std::endl;

        // This is where the exception is thrown...
        m_DBConn.insert( Data["ns"].getString(), BSONDoc );

    } catch( const mongo::DBException& e ){
        std::cout << e.toString() << std::endl;

    }

    m_EntriesMutex.lock();
    m_Entries.pop();
    m_EntriesMutex.unlock();

}
```

Comment: can connect to mongod process using mongo shell on localhost:27017?

Comment: Yes, I can connect just fine in mongo shell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug around in the documentation briefly and stumbled across the startling fact that you can't connect to a mongodb database from the constructor. I had to change this:

```
mongo::DBClientConnection DBConn( "localhost" );
```

to this:

```
mongo::DBClientConnection DBConn;

DBConn.connect( "localhost" );
```